# Solve $x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\dots}}} = 4$

Tags: sequences-and-series, radicals, nested-radicals

Today I faced a strange equation and I didn't manage to find a solution to it:
$$x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\dots}}} = 4$$
Maybe someone will help me to find a way to solve it. By the way, this equation is from high school course.

Comment: What does this have to do with geometric progressions?

Comment: Well this equation was in geometric progressions chapter in my book.

Comment: The exponents form a geometric progression (first term 1, ratio 1/2).

Comment: @GerryMyerson It has _everything_ to do with geometric progressions. :)

Answer (score 47):

$$x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\cdots}}}=x\,x^{1/2}\,x^{1/4}\,x^{1/8}\cdots=x^{1+1/2+1/4+1/8+\cdots}=x^2$$

Comment: I don't understand how this answer could be downvoted.

Comment: @Hakim ,I ask about the R.H. :4 ,I meant where is 4 ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I just realized that your comment could be read as a justification for having downvoted my answer. Is it? And you downvoted this because there is no 4 in it? Seriously?

Answer (score 22):

**Hint**

Divide both sides by $x$ and square them. You should notice something beautiful.

Comment: Thank you, this was really beautiful to discover :)

Comment: Beauty is a major part of mathematics. Please trust the old man ! Cheers :)

Comment: But is $x=2$ a solution? This proves only that no $x\ne2$ is solution.

Comment: @Did One would only need to mention that the "iterated thing" converges.

Comment: @Hakim "Mention"? No, prove!

Comment: @Did Of course, my intention behind stating "mention" was to leave the convergence proof as an exercise to the careful reader.

Comment: @Hakim Which is an odd choice, since proving one has a solution (as opposed to the trivial identification of a possible solution) is the main problem. (Say, Hakim, why are you not commenting on *your* answer?)

Answer (score 7):

An alternative way
$$x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\cdots}}}=4\implies \sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\cdots}}}}=2.$$
Now observe that $$ \sqrt{x\underbrace{\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\cdots}}}}_{2}}=2.$$
Therefore your equation reduces to $$\sqrt{2x}=2\implies 2x=4\implies x=2.\tag{$x>0$}$$

Comment: Elegant. I'm a little confused on how sqrt(2x) = 2 became 2|x| = sqrt(2), though.

Comment: Oh, 2|x| = 4 makes sense now.

Comment: As commented on another answer: "But is $x=2$ a solution? This proves only that no $x≠2$ is solution."

Answer (score 6):

Well, since it hasn't been said yet and you mentioned it was in the geometric progressions chapter of your book, note that the equation can be rewritten as

$$x^{1+1/2+1/4+1/8+...}=4$$

So there's your geometric progression.  Note that $x$ should be positive.

Comment: It has been said, explicitely in a comment and implicitely in an answer.

Comment: I didn't think of it this way. Nice.

Comment: @Did Hmm...  Guess I didn't load new answers and comments.  There were 2 answers when I started typing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A general approach to solve such problems is to exploit self similarity. In this particular problem, the term within the first square root is just the left hand side itself. Thus

$$
x\sqrt{4}=4.
$$

As pointed out by Did in the comments to other questions,  this shows that if a solution exists, then it is unique and equals $2$.

To show that $2$ is indeed a solution,  you need to go the route via geometric series. (As an aside,  geometric series themselves can be solved via self similarity:
$
s:=1+q+q^2+\dots
\Rightarrow s=1+qs
$)

Answer (score -2):

The power of given variabe is in the term of sum of G.P . The indices of x is such that 1+1/2+1/4+......
Because we know that the infinite sum of G.P:
Sn = a/(1-r) where r=common ratio